# Why am I able to use a method name instead of a delegate in this argument?

Tags: c#, delegates

```
public delegate void HandlerDelegate(int val);

public class Process
{
    public static void Execute(HandlerDelegate del)
    {
        del(5);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       //HandlerDelegate handler = Task; normally I would do this first
        Process.Execute(Task); // but this works - how?
    }

    public static void Task(int val)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(val);
    }         

}
```

I understand that a delegate is a reference to a method, but how am I able to pass what looks like a method name to a method that accepts a delegate as its argument?

Comment: Because there is an *implicit conversion* from the "Method Group" to the appropriate delegate. A delegate is **not** a reference to a method, however. Methods are **not** first-class citizens.

Comment: @pst How would it best be described, then?

Comment: I would say a delegate type represents something that is "callable". In the above example the *implicit conversions* make it appear that the Method is passed, but it is not. There is an intermediate object which acts as a proxy and knows how to invoke the particular Method (on a particular instance). This differs from languages like JavaScript or Python where methods *are just functions* themselves.

Comment: @pst I was using this from msdn: "A delegate is a type that references a method."  I guess i was interpreting the wrong way.  So behind the scenes, is it basically doing what the previous line is, except with some type of temporary variable?

Comment: Both code "works" the same; there is an conversion from the Method Group to the particular delegate type (HandlerDelegate here) -- e.g. how did it turn "Task" into an object of type "HandlerDelegate"?. It comes down to language rules of *when* and *why* such conversions are possible -- which is where I am waiting for other people. Note that MSDN says a type that **references** a Method. Not that **is** a Method.

Comment: @pst Right, I thought that it referenced a method and wasn't saying that it was one. Anyway, you've cleared up some of the mystery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its just one of the many ways of instantiating a delegate

For Example:

```
public delegate void Del<T>(T item);//delegate
public void Notify(int i) { }//instance method
```

Different ways to instantiate the above delegate **Del** with the method **Notify**

```
Del<int> d1 = new Del<int>(Notify);
```

OR

```
Del<int> d2 = Notify;
```

[More info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173176%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)